# uint64_t writes in 32 bit machine

Tags: c++, architecture, synchronization, multiprocessing

When 2 process communicating via shared memory on 32 bit solaris i386 Arch

1. Is it guaranteed that for the value of uint64_t datatype, (**value < 2^32**) is written in single memory location and (**value > 2^32** ) is written in 2 memory location?
2. Is the 32 bit memory read is atomic.?

Comment: Are you specifically asking what guarantees 32-bit Solaris provides on i386? Or is this a generic question about 64-bit operations on 32-bit platforms in C++?

Answer (score 3):

A 64-bit value is always written into 64 bits of memory!<sup>1</sup>  The write is almost certainly not atomic (unless the architecture explicitly guarantees this).

---

<sub>1. Except, of course, when it's not written to memory at all (i.e. when there's no [register spill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_spill).  But that's beside the point.</sub>